# Self Join in Eloquent - How To Call

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I recently asked a question regarding a self join

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592793/self-join-in-eloquent)

I got a great answer but I'm not sure how to call it.

I need to do this query:

```
SELECT t2.title FROM products t1, products t2
WHERE t1.id = $id 
AND t2.color_id = t1.color_id AND
t2.id != $id
```

I now have this on my products model:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'color_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'color_id');
}
```

But how do I call this?

```
Product::with('children')->find(1);
```

The above gets the product with id 1 but also gets children that have a color_id of 1, I need to get children who have a color_id the same as the id as product 1.

eg.

Products

```
id | title | color_id
 1    dvd       2
```

When I select row 1 it should select all other products with a color_id of 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self Join in Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592793/self-join-in-eloquent)

Comment: This questions should be deleted, what you are asking here is the same you are asking on your other question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe your relations are not the way they're supposed to be. Usually it's one column (foreign key - color_id in your case) having a value of the other one (usually primary key - id in your case).

What you have is basically a value the records share or a "category". So your products are not "children" but rather siblings (have the same parent color).

Since `with` method is not build as a JOIN statement but as eager loading (separate query) you can do that manually.

Probably the most straight forward way:

```
$product1 = Product::find(1);
$children = Product::where('id', '<>', $product1->id)->
    where('color_id', $product1->color_id)->
    get();
```

You can add `select('title')` to the second "builder" to get only title but that would not be your model anymore. Or you can use `lists('title')` to extract only titles if that's what you need.

**UPDATE:**

If you decide you need the JOIN after all I'd suggest going with raw query builder and leave the Eloquent out of it:

```
$res = DB::table('products as t1')->
    select('t2.title')->
    join('products AS t2', 't2.color_id', '=', 't1.color_id')->
    where('t1.id', 1)->
    where('td2.id', '<>', 't1.id')->
    get();
```

I believe it should build something similar to what you need.

Comment: Thanks but my original query would be more efficient.

Comment: Then use actual query builder methods. Eloquent does not do joins.

Comment: Eloquent DOES do joins

Answer (score 6):

You can try this way:

```
// Category.php
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id'); // you may use self::class instead of Category::class
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id'); // you may use self::class instead of Category::class
}

// To access
$category->children; // sub-categories collection

$category->parent; // parent instance
```

based on : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/self-join-in-eloquent-model?page=1

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do as follow :

```
$id = 1;
$product = Product::with('children')->whereHas('children', function($q) use ($id)
{
    $q->where('color_id', $id);
})->find($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

### See [Advanced Join Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) and adapt from my example here.

It took me a long time to wrap my head around Laravel joins.

This:

```
$postIds = DB::table('comments as t1')
     ->select('t1.*')
            ->leftJoin('comments as t2', function ($join) {
                $join->on('t1.postId', '=', 't2.postId')
                ->on('t1.created_at', '<', 't2.created_at');
            })
            ->where('t2.id', '=', null)
            ->orderBy('t1.created_at', 'DESC')
            ->simplePaginate(20)
            ->pluck('postId');
```

seems to be the way to get an array of the postIds that would be revealed by this:

```
SELECT     t1.* 
FROM     comments a         
LEFT OUTER JOIN     comments b
 ON t1.postId = t2.postId        
 AND t1.created_at < t2.created_at 
WHERE     t2.id IS NULL     
ORDER BY t1.created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT subcat.CategoryName as SubCat cat.CategoryName as Category FROM bn_bas_categories cat, bn_bas_categories subcat WHERE cat.CategoryID = subcat.ParentID;
```